# How to fire a jquery plugin with php?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to trigger a jquery plugin called ['Sweet Alert'](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) from within some php code but it's not firing.

This is what I'm trying:

```
echo "<script>
 swal(\"Success\", \"Your profile has been updated\", \"success\");
</script>";
```

This does work:

```
echo "<script>
 alert(\"Success\");
</script>";
```

And to test the plugin is loading correctly I tried this at the bottom of the page which fires the plugin.

```
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 swal("Success", "Your profile has been updated", "success");
   }); 
   </script>
```

What have I got wrong?

Comment: And adding `document.ready` to `echo`? And opening developers console and check errors?

Comment: Include jquery plugins before php code.

Comment: That worked. Thank you.